# How can I download a package and all of its dependencies with apt-get

Tags: linux, apt, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to use apt-get to download a package and all of it's depenedcies.
Those packages will have to be installed on computers with no internet connection, so in addition to the base package I also need to all of the package's dependcies as well.
Is there an easy way to do this (like in muon package manager)?

I know that I can use the **apt-get download** command for this, but I don't want to manually specify each package that muon recommends to install or upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command simulates installing a package and displays all dependencies (hint: use grep):

```
apt-get -s install package
```

Comment: +1 for the hint. I ended up using apt-offline.

Answer (score 0):

from the non-networked machine, run `apt-get --print-uris install packagename`  this wont try to download, but will give a list of urls it would download if it were networked.  You can then take this list to another machine to do the downloading.

Also take a look at the apt-zip package, which creates a script using this output that you can run on another machine to wget the packages.